# Xmonad - Force application to open in specific size?

Tags: xmonad

If I open Pidgin, I'd like it to open on a specific workspace but also at a specific size.  Currently when I open it, it will take up have the screen next to my web browser.  Is there a way to make it open with only like a 1/3 of the screen instead?